# MySQL query called from Java - configure the "WHERE" parameter

Tags: java, mysql

I am connecting to a mysql db from standalone java application. My application uses several filters that determine, which data will be selected from db.

In some cases, I would like to construct the select command in a way, that its "WHERE" parameter is ignored and selects all values from db instead.

This is my example:

```
String query = "SELECT * from messages WHERE type='" + type + "' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

The variable **type** can contain some specific type that matches the Varchar of the items in my db. However, a user can set the **type** to "all values" (or something like that, I hope this is clear enough), in which case, the query would select ALL values from db (it will ignore the where parameter).

I know I could do this by simply putting some if statements in my code and call a different select command in every branch, but this would be highly ineffective in case that several specifications (attributes inside WHERE parameter) are used.

For example:

```
String query = "SELECT * from messages WHERE type='" + type + "' AND time='" + time + "'  ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I am not sure whether this is even possible to do. If not, sorry about dumm question... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to do it through code, nothing in SQL to do what you want to do.  Typically, people use ORM like Hibernate and construct the query in more secure way (to avoid SQL injection) instead of using String concatenation.

This is how it is done in Hibernate: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Type class and a Time class and so on. This classes would contain a function called `getSQL()` which returns the type or in case of all types "".

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause let you filter the dataset according to several predicates. Not specifying it means no filtering, hence all possible values for any predicates you would add.

If you consider the `WHERE` clause as a predicate, and predicates as either sets of predicates or atomic predicates, you can easily produce your clause by walking through the predicate nest and generate the needed string. If the string comes back empty, just elide the `WHERE` clause altogether.

```
interface Predicate {
    public String toString();
}

// further derive this class for specific predicates
class AtomPredicate implements Predicate {
    public AtomPredicate(){}
    public toString() {}
}

 // basic predicate set 
class SetPredicate implements Predicate {
    public SetPredicate(String connector){this.connector = connector;}
    private ArrayList<Predicate> set;
    private String connector;
    public toString(){
        String res, tmp;
        int i;
        if (set.size() == 0) return "";
        while (res.size() == 0 && i < set.size()) {
            res = set[i++].toString();
        }
        for (; i < set.size(); ++i) {
            tmp = set[i].toString();
            if (tmp.size() > 0) 
                res += connector + " " + tmp; 
        }
        if (res.size() > 0) 
            return "(" + res + ")";
    }

    class WhereClause {
        public WhereClause() {}
        private Predicate predicate;
        public toString(){ 
            String res = predicate.toString();
            if (res.size() > 0) return "WHERE " + res;
            return "";
        }
    }
```

You can start from that basic outline, and expand as needed. You should however try to look for an existing solution first, like the jboss library linked in another answer, to avoid reinventing the wheel.